# javascript Data.parse in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, date-parsing, ruby-2.1

I want to use [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to render some historical data. The issue is the chart is working with dates which are parsed using `Data.parse` function. As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
```

For example:

```
Date.parse("01/01/2013 08:00")
1357020000000
```

As I do not want to do JavaScript manipulation over the returned `JSON` I want to do the conversion in `ruby`. Is there such `ruby` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse("01/01/2013 08:00").strftime('%Q')
#=> "1357027200000"
```

Is this what you want?

For more Information see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Comment: This gives me `Tue, 01 Jan 2013 08:00:00 +0000`. I need milliseconds since 1970.

Comment: Updated answer to return millis.

Comment: yes it is working now. I am going to accepted it, even though I done this in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this in the `postresql` like this [search for EPOCH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) :

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM my_date) as my_date
```

It gives me:

```
1410705430.59685
```

Then in the partial I just called `to_i`